# How to display values from a linked list to a text area

Tags: java

I would like to display all values from the linked list to text area including the ones that the user will have to enter.
Also when the user adds more names, I would like the text area to display the next name almost like a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
String name = Username.getText(); //get text from text field
String name2 = mylist.getText();//get text from text area
mylist.setText(""); //remove all text in text area
Queue<String> myQ=new LinkedList<String>();

    myQ.add(name2);//add already writen data in text area
    myQ.add(name);//add text field data

    for(String str : myQ){ //iterate
        //System.out.print(str +" ");
        mylist.append(str +" ");//append into text area

    }
```

*Edit 1:*

As you also want to remove element from queue so use this modify code.

**Add Button:**

```
    Queue<String> myQ=new LinkedList<>();
    int count=0;
    private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    myQ.add(++count+":" + Username.getText());//add into queue
    mylist.setText("");//use to insert new data
    mylist.append(myQ +"\n");//insert queue object into text area
    myQ.peek();//get top value of queue


    }
```

**Remove Button:**

```
    private void RegisterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    myQ.remove();//remove first element
    System.out.print(myQ);
    mylist.setText("");
    mylist.append(myQ +" ");

  }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, basically I am trying to build a queuing system (FIFO), user is added to the Queue, then placed on the bottom of the textarea, much appreciated if you can help

Comment: In this code when you enter name in text field and click on button then name will placed into text area then again when you want to add another it's will show something like this : user first enter tom and then omore so output will be -> tom omore, tell me what you want to do with output

Comment: Thanks for the help Omore, I love what you have done, I have one last part I am trying to figure out, When the user is deleted I would like the user who was below to take their position in the queue and for it to be displayed in the text area